# Webpack dev-server cannot see code changes

Tags: webpack, config, webpack-dev-server, livereload

I start learning about webpack configuration and cannot see the effect of changes made on files.
My webpack.config.js

...

```
   devServer: {
    watchFiles: ["src/**/*.js", "css/**/*", "src/**/*.html"],
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    },
    liveReload: true,
    port: 5000,
    open: true,
  },
```

...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think is something related to static instead of in memory ...

Answer (score 1):

Solved...
Add devMiddleware like here:

```
devServer: {
devMiddleware: {
  writeToDisk: true,
},
```